# Load a Vuforia's Unity Scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm trying to load a Unity Vuforia Scene after the user has singed in  with a form but when tries to switch to the vuforia's scene; always show me a error telling me that vuforia has failed to initialize and I must do it manually.So, how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please add your licence key to the project first.
Register at https://developer.vuforia.com/ then you could acquire licence key on LicenceManager.